# Why is my image not showing on the design view? Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have the following (very simple, I know) XAML code in the main page of my visual studio project. Why is the image not showing? All I have done is drag it using the toolbox menu and then added the file path.

```
    <Page
    x:Class="SnapIt.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SnapIt"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="White">

    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="camera" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="163,115,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="C:/Users/user/Desktop/camera.png"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Did you try building? The designer can be very; very; slow sometimes.

Comment: What do you mean building? I tried to input the image by dragging an 'image' from the toolbox and then assigning the source to the file path of the desired image.

Comment: I'm saying for the designer to update, you occasionally need to build the project.